# Android collapsing layout once collapsed, doesn't show up again

Tags: android, material-design

I wrote an XML for `AppBarLayout` with collapsible `ImageView`. And, I want only the image view being collapsed Whereas, the toolbar should get pinned when I scroll up. I'm able to produce a similar thing, but once the `ImageView`is collapsed, it doesn't show up again on scrolling down.

I suspect that the problem is with `layout_scrollFlags` but I tried every flag. On applying other flags, the toolbar doesn't get pinned. Can anyone point me where i have done the mistake?

here's my XML:

`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/rsz_bg_cover"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="#EEE"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/calendar_white"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks koraokyo, 
Your suggestions did make the hings clear for me. However, the solution you provided were not solving the problem. Hence I played around and things seem to work as I wanted. I moved the `TabLayout` inside `AppBarLayout` under another `CollapsingToobarLayout` and everything is perfect now. here's my `AppBarLayout` now.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/rsz_bg_cover"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="#EEE" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is designed to be the sole child of a `AppBarLayout`. Instead of having the `TabLayout` as a child of the `AppBarLayout`, move it outside (so it is a child of the `CoordinatorLayout`) and anchor it to the app bar.

```
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="#EEE"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"/>
```

Comment: I changed the content as suggested by you. The things are okay now, but the tab layout is overlapping (half-way) to the  toolbar / appbar. I mean it is not exactly under the `AppBarLayout`. Any comments on that?

Comment: layout_gravity="bottom" as well

Comment: That fixed the things but now viewpager overlaps the tablayout. Will try fixing it.

Answer (score -1):

I think that's the problem `ViewPager`. Try use `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` or `NestedScrollView` instead `ViewPager`.
You can see more [this tut](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout) and [this design](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).